# Configure Artifactory for symbol-packages (*.snupkg)

Tags: artifactory

In the last year or so, dotnet and nuget teams introduced symbol packages with the naming convention `*.snupkg`. Nuget.org fully supports indexing these.

How do we configure Artifactory to do the same?

Effectively, we need this feature for Artifactory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg

Comment: Right now artifactory only have partial symbols support, and that is only if you have artifactory installed on a windows server.
If you want to get this functionality now, it seems to be proget or through TFS package management. Other than that, try and make a request to JFrog.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Microsoft+Symbol+Server) help?